# what is the c code to execute xeyes or xclock?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

which function do i use to give such linux terminal calls in my c program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`system` would be the correct [posix call](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system). It takes a pointer to char as the command to be executed. See `man 3 system`. However `system` can be completely corrupted by environment variables and an harder-to-use alternative is `exec` (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)).

A little example to illustrate:

```
system("xeyes");
system("rm -rf $HOME"); /* never ever try this, really */
```

Comment: Have you included the quotes? ie system("xeyes"), NOT system(xeyes)

Comment: @Noel I don't think he has. Thus my examples and clarification.